# trim everything before last slash vb.net

Tags: vb.net, indexof

Yesterday I learned to trim the file name off a file location using the flowing code

```
    Dim NEWPATH As String = (inventorApp.ActiveDocument.FullFileName)
    NEWPATH = NEWPATH.Substring(0, NEWPATH.fIndexOf("\"c))
```

This is realy neat because it is a more reliaable/ stable way to what I was using before... Haha today though i want the reverse I want to trim everything before the last slash how can i do that?

also just out of curiosity whats the lowercase c for in ("\"c) namely the code also works well without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split() function or this

```
Dim mystr As String = "Dr. John Smith 123 Main Street 12345"
Dim cut_at As String = "Smith"
Dim x As Integer = InStr(mystr, cut_at)

Dim string_before As String = mystr.Substring(0, x - 2)
Dim string_after As String = mystr.Substring(x + cut_at.Length-1)
```

Comment: This will not work for the OP's needs. They are looking to trim all Directories off of a file path. Therefore the `cut_at` value will be ``\`` and unless the file is on the root of the drive, the `InStr()` function will return the position of the first ``\`` in the file path, not the last. At a minimum the `InStrRev()` function should be used instead. Secondly if this code is being used cross platform, ``\`` is only the directory separator in Windows, not Unix or Mac.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than fiddling with substrings, you can use methods of the [`Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim fullpath as String = inventorApp.ActiveDocument.FullFileName

'What you're after now - the filename
Dim justTheFileName as String = Path.GetFileName(fullpath)

'a replacement for what you're already doing to get the folder name
Dim justTheFolderName as String = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullpath)
```

---

The lowercase `c` in `"\"c`  denotes that you want a `Char` rather than a `String`, which is what [this particular overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx) of `IndexOf` takes, but there's a [`String` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) too, so it would work equally well without the `c`.

Comment: FYI, You need to either import System.IO in order to use the `Path` class or qualify the namespace in your code. MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx   .NET Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,090eca8621a248ee

Comment: The VB IDE will offer to add the `Imports` statement provided there is a reference to the assembly (which is automatically the case for `System.IO`.

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ Yes - and the same holds true for any class you use, of course.  However, I don't feel that all answers that point out the existence of a class should need to go into the detail of how to reference, import and use classes.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the confirmation on that - I've been using ReSharper for so long I forget what's R# and what's VS...

Comment: @JamesThorpe I know you know that the `Imports` statement is needed, I only added that comment for the sake of any future visitors whom may not know that and are not using VS like Plutonix mentioned. You got my +1 for being the correct answer.

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ That's fine - but comments are transient, and could be removed at any time.  I'm just saying why I won't be adding that info into my answer on the off chance the comments are removed :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `LastIndexOf()` to create a substring that will contain only what's after the last slashe :

```
Dim fullpath As String = inventorApp.ActiveDocument.FullFileName

Dim FileName As String = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\"))
```

I like this one because it is more general (i.e. you can recover the file extension by replacing `"\"` by `"."`). However, if you know for sure that you are working with pathes to files, prefer James Thorpe's solution, using `System.IO.Path`

Comment: Or you could just use [`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx).